# Upload video file from google storage bucket to youtube programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, youtube-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a video uploader and want to upload a video file from Google storage bucket to a Youtube channel. I know how to use Youtube's APIv3 to upload a video from my local machine, but I can't figure out how to get a file from Google storage bucket and upload it Youtube. Is there a way to do this? If so, how do I do it or find more information?